# Using the Redis script in SpringBoot, an error is reported: attempt to compare nil with number at

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, lua

In SpringBoot, I use RedisTemplate to execute the Lua script to implement the interface current limiter. The script is as follows：

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local count = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local expiration = tonumber(ARGV[2])
if redis.call('EXISTS', key) == 0 then
    redis.call('SET', key, 1)
    redis.call('EXPIRE', key, expiration)
    return 1
else
    local current_count = tonumber(redis.call('GET', key))
    if current_count == nil then
        redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, 'current_count is nil')
        redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, current_count)
        return 10
    end
    if current_count >= count then
        return current_count
    else
        redis.call('INCR', key)
        return current_count + 1
    end
end
```

What I don't understand is that it was normal for him to deposit in Redis for the first time, but this error occurred in the second accumulation:attempt to compare nil with number at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.lettuceexceptionconverter.convert

But the fetched value should not be a nil, and I also judged whether the current_count is nil or not. Obviously, the program did not enter this judgment, which means it is not nil

But when executing this section of code: if current_count >= count then ，I get an error that tells me that nil cannot be compared with type number? what's the situation? ? ? This surprised me.

Has anyone specified why, please explain, thank you.

no redundant operation.